# Unable to put a WITH FUNCTION clause in a BEGIN/END block

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, with-statement

Why doesn't the below code compile:

```
DECLARE
c number;
BEGIN
WITH
FUNCTION calculate(i IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
AS
r number;
BEGIN
  r := i*i;
  RETURN r;
END;
select calculate(1) INTO c from dual;
END;
```

giving the following error:

```
Error report -
*ORA-06550: line 5, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

whereas:

```
WITH
FUNCTION calculate(i IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
AS
r number;
BEGIN
  r := i*i;
  RETURN r;
END;
select calculate(1) from dual;
```

compiles?

**Oracle version information**

> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
> PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: It's helpful to include the error you get from the first version. But `select into` isn't quite the same as `select`. It's possible the `with function ...` syntax hasn't made it into the PL/SQL version yet; although as the syntax diagrams don't even show the CTE syntax it's hard to tell. Are you using 12cR1 or 12cR2 - it might have changed between releases?

Comment: @AlexPoole I've added the information you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construct just doesn't seem to be supported in PL/SQL yet. Presumably it will be added in a future release.

In the meantime it's unpleasant but you could use dynamic SQL, which continues to run your working statement in a SQL context where it is understood:

```
DECLARE
  c number;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
WITH
FUNCTION calculate(i IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  r number;
BEGIN
  r := i*i;
  RETURN r;
END;
select calculate(2) from dual'
  INTO c;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c);
END;
/

4
```

[The documentation for `select into`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345) doesn't show that the `with` clause is supported in PL/SQL even for subquery blocks, but that does work even in earlier releases. So it doesn't refer to the new PL/SQL declaration syntax either. Based on experiments in Oracle's Live SQL platform, which is running 12.2.0.1, it isn't supported in 12cR2 either.

Comment: Seems consistent with suggestion in https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#plsql-support

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if that "due in a future release" is based on something official, or hope/assumption. (Probably valid; I'd expect it to catch up at some point.)  I couldn't see anything about this on Oracle's sites or MOS - I may well have missed something though.